# VB.net, exporting RTF TextBox content to Excel Cell

Tags: excel, vb.net, interop, rtf

I have a RichTextFormat Textbox than contains multiple line, Bold, Underline and Italic text. I need both the text AND the fontstyle to be paste in an Excel cell, so "**SAMPLE**" will still be "**SAMPLE**" and not "SAMPLE" or "SAMPLE\b0\par".

I currently tried

```
ExcelApp.Range("C2").Value = RTFTB.Rtf
```

That gave me

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1036{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0
>   Calibri;}}
>   \viewkind4\uc1\pard\b\f0\fs23 SAMPLE BOLD\b0\par
>   \par
>   \i SAMPLE ITALIC\i0\par
>   \par
>   \ul SAMPLE UNDERLINE\par
>   \par
>   \ulnone SAMPLE NORMAL\par
>   }

(RTF code)

And

```
ExcelApp.Range("C2").Value = RTFTB.Text
```

That gave me

> SAMPLE BOLD
>
> SAMPLE ITALIC
>
> SAMPLE UNDERLINE
>
> SAMPLE NORMAL

(Without fontstyle)

Comment: Excel **does not** support rtf directly...

Comment: Is there a way to keep Bold, Underline and Italic textformating ?

Comment: A quick Google search showed that most solutions involve copy pasting it into a secondary program (Word) and then pasting it into Excel. Word will convert the formatting into a version that Excel can read.

Comment: I saw that too. I juste hoped that there was something more clean than opening a Word Doc, pasting in, then copying and pasting into Excel as Special/ But thanks !

Comment: As much as I am loath to suggest a Clipboard based solution and in the category as 1st copying to MS Word, you can paste the RTF into a `WebBrowser` control that has been placed in _edit mode_ and then copy that to get the HTML placed on the Clipboard.  Excel can paste the HTML Clipboard format.

Comment: Try with `.Range("C2").PasteSpecial`. It uses the Office ClipBoard, though. So, you first need to copy the rtf text from Excel, then paste it again. See: [File formats that are supported in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/file-formats-that-are-supported-in-excel-0943ff2c-6014-4e8d-aaea-b83d51d46247?ocmsassetID=HP010352464&CorrelationId=aba68397-80c0-4a23-a078-e6a70e1c4b7f&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#BMdatabaseformats).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up NOT doing the RTF to HTML to Excel solution for I didn't had the required skill to do so

Instead I went for this :

- Copy the whole RichTextBox
- Paste it into Word
- Copy the Word document
- Paste it into Excel

It's not perfect, for it becomes an image and not a text, but at least it works.

Here is my code :

```vb
'Phase 1 : Copy the RichTextBox

        TbRTF.SelectAll()
        TbRTF.Copy()
        Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, TbRTF.Rtf)

'Prepare phase 2 : Declare variables

        Dim aDoc As Word.Document = WordApp.Documents.Open("a blank word file.docx")
        Dim TheRange As Word.Range = aDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range

'Phase 2 : Paste into Word

        WordApp.Visible = False

        TheRange.WholeStory()
        TheRange.Paste()

'Phase 3 : Copy from Word

        TheRange.WholeStory()
        WordApp.ActiveDocument.Select()
        WordApp.Selection.Copy()

'Phase 3.5 : Close Word

        aDoc.Close()
        WordApp.Quit()

'Phase 4 : Paste into Excel

        ExcelApp.Range("D" & r).PasteSpecial()

'Phase 4.5 : Close Excel

        Classeur.SaveAs("FinishedExcelFile.xlsx")
        Classeur.Close()
        ExcelApp.Quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Clipboard to transfer information is not something that I like to propose as solution.  However, I know of no way to accomplish your goal without translating the RTF into a sequence of UI Automation commands to simulate adding the text to Excel and then formatting it.

The following method can be used to place RTF on the Clipboard as Html.  It uses the `Webbrowser` control in an editable mode to *convert* the Clipboard's RTF format to Html.  The Html is then placed on the Clipboard.

The overall sequence is:

1. Place the RTF on the Clipboard as RTF
2. Create a WebBrowser Control and set its DocumentText to editable Html.

   In the WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted event handler,
3. Paste the RTF to the WebBrowser.
4. Select all of the Html and copy it.
5. Finally, dispose of the WebBrowser control.

...

```
Public Shared Sub RtfToHtmlClipboard(rtf As String)
    Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, rtf)
    Dim browser As New WebBrowser
    AddHandler browser.DocumentCompleted, Sub(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
                                            Dim wb As WebBrowser = CType(sender, WebBrowser)
                                            wb.Document.ExecCommand("Paste", False, Nothing)
                                            wb.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", False, Nothing)
                                            wb.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", False, Nothing)
                                            wb.Dispose()
                                          End Sub

    browser.DocumentText = "<html><body contenteditable=""true""></body></html>"
End Sub
```

---

Edit:

I use the above to put RTF as HTML on the Clipboard for the user to manually paste.  Hence I did not consider the implications of using a some-what time sensitive usage case such as Excel automation.

For the automation case, it is preferable to not create the control each time.  Further more, it appears as though there are other mechanisms in play when pasting to Excel through automation (possibly related to the Office Clipboard?) that just re-affirms my dislike of using the Clipboard.

However, I found that the following *works* to copy formatted RTF to Excel.  My Office version is ancient (2007), so hopefully this still works on newer versions.  Create a new WinForm application and replace the Form1.VB contents with the following to test it.  On running the code, click the "Excecute" button to create an Excel instance and paste some formmated RTF to it.

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents rtb As RichTextBox
    Private WithEvents btnExecute As Button
    Private editableBrowser As WebBrowser

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Setup()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Setup()
        editableBrowser = New WebBrowser With {
            .DocumentText = "<html><body contenteditable=""true""></body></html>"
        }

        btnExecute = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        rtb = New System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox()
        SuspendLayout()

        btnExecute.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(580, 20)
        btnExecute.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(135, 50)
        btnExecute.TabIndex = 0
        btnExecute.Text = "Execute"
        btnExecute.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        AddHandler btnExecute.Click, AddressOf btnExecute_Click

        rtb.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(20, 20)
        rtb.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(450, 350)
        rtb.TabIndex = 1

        ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 450)
        Controls.Add(Me.rtb)
        Controls.Add(Me.btnExecute)
        ResumeLayout()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExecute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ExcelWork()
        COMCleanUp()
    End Sub

    Private Function GetRTF1() As String
        rtb.Clear()
        ' add some text and format it.
        Dim formattedText As String = "some sample rtf"
        rtb.Text = "This is " & formattedText & " to format and copy."
        rtb.CreateControl()
        rtb.SelectionStart = rtb.Find(formattedText)
        rtb.SelectionLength = formattedText.Length
        rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Red
        rtb.SelectionFont = New Font(Font.FontFamily, Font.Size + 2.0F, FontStyle.Bold)
        Return rtb.Rtf
    End Function

    Sub ExcelWork()
        Dim app As New Excel.Application
        Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = app.Workbooks.Add()
        Dim rng As Excel.Range = DirectCast(wb.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet).Range("A1")

        PlaceRtfFAsHtmlOnClipboard(GetRTF1)
        ' for some reason rng.PasteSpecial just pastes as 
        ' unformatted text.  manual pasting results in formatted 
        ' text.
        ' The Worsheet.Paste method as well as the Worsheet.PasteSpecial
        ' methods will paste the Clipboard HTML format
        rng.Worksheet.PasteSpecial(Format:="HTML")
        'rng.Worksheet.Paste(rng)

        wb.Saved = True
        app.Visible = True  ' hand control over to user
        app.UserControl = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub PlaceRtfFAsHtmlOnClipboard(rtf As String)

        ' Clear the browser
        editableBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", False, Nothing)
        editableBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Cut", False, Nothing)

        '  put rtf on clipboard
        Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, rtf)

        ' and paste to the editable broswer
        editableBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Paste", False, Nothing)
        editableBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", False, Nothing)

        ' copy the html to the Clipboard
        editableBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", False, Nothing)
    End Sub

    Private Sub COMCleanUp()
        Do
            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        Loop While System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AreComObjectsAvailableForCleanup
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: It would be what I'm looking for, but I get `Pastespecial method of range class failed` when trying to paste.

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't traduce RTF to HTML directly

Comment: @Thryn,  I posted some sample Excel automation code to demonstrate paste RTF to Excel.  Give that a try.